# ImageBox graphics mistake

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, graphics

I am attempting to draw a list of polygons to an imagebox. so far I am only getting a diagonal black line in the top left hand corner of the screen. The points are as follows:

20,20
0,20
20,0
40,40

200,100
0,20
20,0
20,20

100, 200
0, 200
200,0
250, 450

150,130
1,20
20,0
10,20

```
    private void pictureBox1_Paint_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int jobIndex = 0;
        int trussIndex = 0;

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        foreach (Member m in jobArray[jobIndex].trusses[trussIndex].members)
        {
            Point[] pointArray = new Point[m.poly.Points.Count()];
            //m.poly.Points.CopyTo(pointArray, 0);
            int index =0;
            foreach(System.Windows.Point p in m.poly.Points)
            {
                pointArray[index].X = (int)p.X;
                pointArray[index].Y = (int)p.Y;
                index++;
            }
            Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(m.color);

            g.DrawPolygon(myPen, pointArray);
            g.FillPolygon(myBrush, pointArray);

        }
    }
```

Any Ideas as to why the polygons do not appear on the imagebox?
The colors are no the issue nor the size of the box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your using the Paint event to call this method, ensure you have the data available when it is called. The paint event is not constantly called, so if you add data to be drawn you will need to call the pictureBox1.Invalidate() method to force the paint event.

I'm sure you'll see this sooner or later, but you should create an image (Bitmap) object and assign it to the Image property of the PictureBox. Then use the Graphics.FromImage(_image) to get your graphics object. If you don't then your image won't stay if the window is covered then comes back into focus or you drag it off screen then back kinda thing.

```
private Bitmap _bitMap;
private Graphics _graphic;
Pen myPen;

public Constructor()
{
    _bitMap = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width,pictureBox1.Height);
    _graphic = Graphics.FromImage(_bitMap);
    pictureBox1.Image = _bitMap;
    myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
}
private void DataAdded()
{
    int jobIndex = 0;
    int trussIndex = 0;

    foreach (Member m in jobArray[jobIndex].trusses[trussIndex].members)
    {
        //Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black); //Don't instantiate in a loop
        SolidBrush myBrush = new SolidBrush(m.color);
        _graphic.DrawPolygon(myPen, m.poly.Points.ToArray());
        _graphic.FillPolygon(myBrush, m.poly.Points.ToArray());
    }
    pictureBox1.Image = _bitMap; //Don't think you need this, but I don't remember
}
```

Hope this helps